# SSIS - Writing to Excel After Skipping Rows

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to write data to an excel spreadsheet after skipping x number of rows...excel is my destination and a sql query would be my source?

My scenario is one where i have a lot of header rows that i need to skip before data insertion. I would like to do this in an SSIS package. I am using SQL 2008 and Excel 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you right click on the excel connection manager at the bottom of the page than click options , there is a setting called  FirstRowHasColumnName set it to FALSE .let me know if it helps , didn't really understand if you just want  to skip the first row that is the name of the columns from SQL query or more , there are other ways

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to modify your SQL query to exclude the header rows. If you can't do that then you need some logic to determine if the row is a header row (like checking if a certain field is a number):

If you can do that then you can do this:

- read all columns in as text
- Put in a derived column where you generate a new column `IsHeader` using your logic
- Use Conditional Output to filter out the rows where your `IsHeader` is true
- Use Data Conversion or Derived column to convert the columns to correct datatype
- Output to Excel as usual